Can you perceive when a creature "starts its turn"?
Definitions
Reaction

A Reaction is a special action taken in response to a trigger defined in the Reaction’s description...

Ready Action

You take the Ready action to wait for a particular circumstance before you act. To do so, you take this action on your turn, which lets you act by taking a
Reaction before the start of your next turn.
First, you decide what perceivable circumstance will trigger your Reaction. Then, you choose the action you will take in response to that trigger...

Path of the World Tree Barb

Level 6: Branches of the Tree
Whenever a creature you can see starts its turn within 30 feet of you while your Rage is active, you can take a Reaction...


It doesn't seem to me like "starting a turn" is perceivable, because clearly a "turn" is an abstraction over the narrative of kinetic conflict, but the rulebook itself offers a very cheap Reaction in response to exactly that circumstance as a stock character feature.
So - can PCs React to turn starts more or less whenever they want, now? Or is this somehow a case of "specific beats general"?

FWIW, the workaround would of course be to trigger based on the entity "doing anything". If they walk, attack, speak, etc, it will almost certainly be on their turn. The only risk would be them taking a reaction outside their own turn, which is unlikely. I imagine you knew this already, but figured I'd type it out for anyone just looking for a solution. Great question overall, interesting to think about and you could certainly try to convince your DM since really, who cares. It's not going to break the game.

@jerclarke The main problem with using "moves or takes an action" as a trigger is that the reaction triggers after the trigger, so you can't catch the start of a creature's turn this way.

Ah yeah. It’s not as good as “when their turn starts” in that sense. But then again, that’s what makes it a hack I guess. There’s no logic to being able to act based on nothing having happened yet.

@RyanC.Thompson I'm not so sure - nothing about the rule seems to restrict the perceivable action to be discrete. That is, "starting to move" is different from "moves"; and you could argue that "starting" is instantaneous with the character's perception of the movement...

Based on the text you have quoted, readied (re)actions cannot be triggered by the start of a turn, but other reaction can be.
The rules you quote state that a reaction occurs in response to "a trigger." The rules don't require that reactions, generally, be restricted to perceivable triggers.
Readied actions, on the other hand, are a subset of all reactions, and they have additional rules: specifically, that a "perceivable circumstance will trigger" the reaction.
So readied actions must be triggered by something perceptible—probably not the start or end of a turn or any other event that is purely a meta-game concept. That doesn't mean that other reactions that aren't readied actions have the same rule, though.
To add, this is essentially the same as the rules for D&D 5e (2014); see for example this question.

Yes
The rules exist to allow us as players to have our characters do things at certain times. If the start of your own turn isn't perceivable in some way then it leads to all sorts of things like being able to take a turn whenever you want because you don't know if it is or isn't your turn yet.
People like to assume that the characters don't know what a turn is but every rule is just an abstraction of something the characters see or do, so maybe some pedant might want you to say "as soon as any other character takes a move, action or bonus action" but that's just needless mental gymnastics.
Do things the easy way, just react when turns start.
